# "Group by" expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some problems trying to print department_id, department_name and the sum of salaries of each department and I can't figure out why. I get the error: 00979 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

[image]

```
SELECT d.department_id, d.department_name, SUM(e.salary)
FROM departments d, employees e
WHERE d.department_id = e.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_id;
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add the `name` to the `group by` expression.  Along the way, also fix the query to use explicit `join` syntax:

```
SELECT d.department_id, d.department_name, SUM(e.salary)
FROM departments d JOIN
     employees e
     ON d.department_id = e.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_id, d.department_name;
```

Although you didn't ask, I will point out that your version of the query does make sense and is ANSI-compliant (although most databases don't support this feature).  You are aggregating by a primary key, so bringing in additional columns is allowed -- although Oracle does not support this feature.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.department_id, d.department_name, SUM(e.salary)
FROM departments d, employees e
WHERE d.department_id = e.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_id, d.department_name;
```

Just needed to add the department_name column in your group by clause.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you can aggregate the department name as well using `MIN()` or `MAX()`:

```
SELECT d.department_id, MAX(d.department_name) AS department_name
     , SUM(e.salary) AS department_salary
  FROM departments d INNER JOIN employees e
    ON d.department_id = e.department_id
 GROUP BY d.department_id;
```

Note that I updated your syntax from the old ANSI standard to the newer one. If you prefer the older syntax (as I do), then just use this:

```
SELECT d.department_id, MAX(d.department_name) AS department_name
     , SUM(e.salary) AS department_salary
  FROM departments d, employees e
 WHERE d.department_id = e.department_id
 GROUP BY d.department_id;
```